# Why do I have to pull from my argument before pulling from my array wrt to removing an item from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, nested-loops

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
const removeFromArray = function(arr) {
    let args = Array.from(arguments);
    for(let x=0; x<arr.length; x++) {
        for(let y=1; y<args.length; y++) {
            if(arr[x]===args[y]) {
                arr.splice(x,1);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I can get the code to work if I switch the outer loop with the inner loop.

I just can't figure out logically why it doesn't work if my outer loop pulls from the parameter array first. It works for most things, but it has problems with this for example:

> removefromArray([1,2,3,4], 3, 2)

It only removes 2 leaving 3 untouched.

I thought maybe the loop removes the 2 and pushes 3 down the index.
But in that case, removeFromArray([1,2,3,4], 1, 2, 3, 4) wouldn't work but it does.

What am I not getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splice` will mutate the array. If you're iterating over the array at the same time you `splice`, you'll have to be careful to reset the index back to account for the newly rearranged elements. For example, with `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, if both 2 and 3 match the condition to remove element from the array:

- On one iteration, `x` will be 1, matching value 2. 2 will be removed from the array with `splice`. The array will then become `[1, 3, 4]`.
- If, at this point, you increment `x`, it'll then be 2, so the item at index 2 will be checked. But the item at that index is now 4; the 3 is never checked. Or, if you increment `y`, the index of the argument being checked, then the argument that was just removed won't be checked again.

Either manually decrement the index when a match is found

```js
// Not recommended; verbose, ugly, and impure
const removeFromArray = function(arr) {
    let args = Array.from(arguments);
    for(let x=0; x<arr.length; x++) {
        for(let y=1; y<args.length; y++) {
            if(arr[x]===args[y]) {
                arr.splice(x,1);
                x--;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(removeFromArray([1,2,3,4], 3, 2));
```

or use `.filter` instead:

```js
const removeFromArray = (arr, ...toRemove) => arr.filter(
  item => !toRemove.includes(item)
);

console.log(removeFromArray([1,2,3,4], 3, 2));
```

Also make sure to use the same capitalization - if you define the function as `removeFromArray`, make sure to call it with a capital `F`. (using `removefromArray` instead will throw a ReferenceError)

Comment: Appreciate the breakdown. I'm having some trouble figuring out why removeFromArray([1,2,3,4], 2, 3) works but not if, in the argument, 3 comes before 2. Why does it matter what order it comes in if we pull from the array first?

Comment: `2, 3` happens to work because that's the same order of the elements in the array. Eg index `n` gets compared against 2, which succeeds, so the item gets removed. Then the item at index `n` is 3. The argument index is incremented, so you then compare against index 3, which also succeeds, so the item gets removed. If 3 came *before* 2, you'd be past the `2`'s argument index when the item is first removed, so the new item at that point isn't checked against 2.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh so like an assembly line where the people stay in the same spot but the conveyer belt moves the production. Really appreciate this, I learned a lot